# Using redux hooks outside of a component for code reusability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a functional component as follows and i have a function which has two dispatches. One sets the error message and the other removes the error message after a brief time out period. The functionality of setting errors and clearing comes in many other components therefore I want to have the two dispatch functions in another file to allow code reusability. I am unable to do this as i get an error which says i can only use useDispatch inside a functional component. How do i overcome this ?

**The component**

```
const Checkout = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const setErrors = (payload) => {
   dispatch({
     type: 'SET_ERRORS',
     payload,
   });

  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch({
     type: 'CLEAR_ERRORS',
    });
  }, 2500);
 };

 return (
  <>
 // JSX stuff come here
  <>
 )
}
```

**The reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  message: null,
  status: false,
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_ERRORS':
      return {
        ...state,
        message: action.payload,
        status: true,

      };
    case 'CLEAR_ERRORS':
      return {
        ...state,
        message: null,
        status: false,

      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own custom hook called for example `useErrorDispatcher` and use it in many functional components. Also please note that hooks are only allowed within functional components.

```
export const useErrorDispatcher = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (payload) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_ERRORS', payload});
        setTimeout(() => dispatch({type: 'CLEAR_ERRORS'}), 2500);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const errorDispatcher = useErrorDispatcher();

    return (
        <button onClick={() => errorDispatcher('an error occurred')} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE 2021** with hooks

using `useDispatch` outside of a component will cause errors.

first, import your general `store` from redux and then use the dispatch method. for example:

```
import store from 'YOUR_DESTINATION_TO_REDUX_STORE'

function doSomething() {
    // do your stuff
    
    store.dispatch(YOUR_ACTION())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const setErrors = (payload, dispatch) => {}
```

Modify the `setErrors` function to take the additional argument `dispatch`. Now you should be able to reuse the `setErrors` in many components.